# List the currently loaded assemblies with VS means

Tags: visual-studio

Can I list all the currently loaded assemblies together with related stuff (full names, load context) during a VS debug session? Preferably, in some dockable window.

(The specific problem is I'm getting an `Assembly.Load` error for an assembly that is apparently already loaded. So I need to compare full names and contexts; this is just for context though.)

The question is how to do it 1) with VS means; 2) regardless of current position in the code (sometimes, commands in the Immediate window don't work).

Comment: If your problem is that the already-loaded version of the assembly and the version to be loaded do not match, then this can typically be fixed using an AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event handler. Let me know, and I'll post some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the AppDomain class for that.

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
{
    Console.WriteLine(assembly.FullName);
}
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets the assemblies that have been loaded into the execution context of this application domain.